# Auto backup so I can share the same app data on Bluestacks and phone

Tags: backup, sync, data-transfer, bluestacks, cloud

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5, running Android  6.0.1 Marshmallow. I also have BlueStacks 5.

A group of games I play does not have Google Play transfer, and I thought I could use the import button on BlueStacks and find the file on my phone (save file) and copy that to the import of BlueStacks. However, seeing as every time I play on a different device, I'll have to copy through cable, import, etc.

I was hoping I could set something like OneDrive to backup and sync constantly that specific file (which would get updated as saved). Currently, I have to use Android Studio to access the save file - it is hidden from the operating system.

How can I do this?

Comment: As you might have noticed from using Android Studio, *without root access*, apps can't access other apps' internal data. And with how each app can determine if they're allowed to be backed up systematically, I'm afraid it's almost impossible to do what you want.

Comment: OP's follow-up question: [Android Studio help - data manager - permission denied](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249489/44325)