# Android Studio - data manager - permission denied

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, file-management, android-studio

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5, Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow. I try to access a save file for a game without Google Play cloud backup.

I have managed to get deeper into the file system using Android Studio than using file managers on Windows and devices (as in I can see the game folder now). However, I get permission denied. Everything I try to open, I get permission denied, or similar. (the phone is in debug mode, etc.)

To be honest, I barely know my way around Android Studio, I am not a developer.

How can I give myself permission?

Comment: OP's previous question (for additional context): [Auto backup so I can share the same app data on Bluestacks and phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/249485/44325)

Comment: thanks andrew T.